# How do I deposit bitcoins in my wallet to an exchange?

Tags: wallet

I just want to cash out my coinbase wallet. Can someone give me the simple steps to do this?  Why is this so complicated? Or is it?

Answer (score 1):

Depositing your Bitcoin is easy. Each exchange may be different in the process they use, so it's best to check your exchanges documentation before doing so.

Each exchange will have a link that will forward you to your exchange wallet page. Due note that almost all exchanges are custodial wallets. This means: when you send any cryptocurrency to your exchange addresses, the token or coin is no longer your possession . When you send your asset to the wallet address that is designated for that particular asset, the assets are immediately transferred to a wallet that is controlled by the exchange --and you do not have access to that address.

Although your tokens are transferred to a wallet you don't have custody over, you will still show a balance in your account. When y0u have completed the trades you wanted to make you will withdrawl to your own address of a wallet which you control. The downside too this is--if an exchange becomes insolvent all of a sudden, then you don't get anything back and most likely will never be compensated for your assets.

So choose a notable exchange that you feel you can trust. Do your research to make sure they aren't in a position to become insolvent. (like what happened to Celsius)

But it's simple. Just go to the wallet page on your exchanges website or mobile app and find your deposit address and send your coins to the deposited address. Any reputable exchange will have directions that are obvious during the deposit / withdrawal process. They will most likely have two-factor authorization mechanisms--so be sure that your account access, email address, phone number, google auth, or whatever it is that you use to associate your account is squared away.

Not financial advice. Do your own research,

**edit**
I just read the title and didn't see the coinbase part. Coinbase has a section where you can swap your tokens for USD and then you can withdraw too your connected financial institution. Or you can send them to a custodial wallet like Bitcoin Core or Electrum and then sell privately on services like localbitcoins.